# Android WebView fail to add multiple javascriptinterface

Tags: android, webview

I find that if I use the interface I added before, the webview could not add the javascriptInterface any more. 
Demo1

```js
    this.webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    this.webView.addJavascriptInterface(test1, "test1");
    this.webView.addJavascriptInterface(test11, "test11");
    this.webView.addJavascriptInterface(test2, "test2");
    this.webView.addJavascriptInterface(test22, "test22");

    this.webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.test1.describle('Hello1');");
    this.webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.test11.describle('Hello11');");
    this.webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.test2.describle('Hello2');");
    this.webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.test22.describle('Hello22');");
```

Demo2

```
    this.webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    this.webView.addJavascriptInterface(test1, "test1");
    this.webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.test1.describle('Hello1');");
    this.webView.addJavascriptInterface(test11, "test11");
    this.webView.addJavascriptInterface(test2, "test2");
    this.webView.addJavascriptInterface(test22, "test22");

    this.webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.test1.describle('Hello1');");
    this.webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.test11.describle('Hello11');");
    this.webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.test2.describle('Hello2');");
    this.webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.test22.describle('Hello22');");
```

In the demo2 , when I use the interface such as test11, I will be told that could not find the obj test11

I don't know why. Looking forwards your suggestion

Answer (score 5):

swap loadUrl and addJavascriptInterface, and might make it.

```
this.webView.addJavascriptInterface(test1, "test1");
this.webView.addJavascriptInterface(test11, "test11");
this.webView.addJavascriptInterface(test2, "test2");
this.webView.addJavascriptInterface(test22, "test22");
this.webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: For me it works if I have the loadUrl at the en. It's cruicial however that the interfaces have different naming.